# JSF Primefaces Treetable row number

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treetable

I have an (ajax-enabled) PrimeFaces TreeTable component; when I display the component, I would like to add a unique identifier for each rows (like row number, or wbs code, etc.).

While it is possible to create a field in the managed bean of the TreeTable, is there another way doing this within the `<p:treeTable>` component? Something like `datatable.indexOf` property?

Also, it would be nice, if I could access the beans by their identifier (for example `backingBean.getBean(128)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TreeNode#setRowKey()` for this

The 'getting and setting' in the backingbean is then not needed since you can get to it in the selection by doing NodeSelectEvent#getTreeNode()

The rowkey can also be retrieved by `TreeNode#getRowKey()`

By default the rowkey is something like 0_0_1 (look in the generated [source of the PF example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml)))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I use `rowKey`, how do I access it in the jsf file?

Comment: Designtime it is not present, runtime it is an attribute on the row (data-rk) as can be seen with a browser developer tool.  You can access it easily with jquery. But since you ask all this, are you not just in need of either a primary key or a businesskey? What is your usecase?